# Como puedo leer un archivo txt desde un Script en una vista Blade en Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, ajax

lo que quiero es traer un archivo txt que se encuentra en public, desde un script en una vista Laravel

Tengo mi vista Laravel y dentro un Script que necesito que lea un archivo txt. Como podría hacer?

Comment: por regla se hace siempre en el controlador, JAMAS en la vista para eso es MVC_ reviza https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 1):

el archivo se lee así también

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$fileContents = Storage::get('nombre_del_archivo');
```

**NOTA SIGERIDA**

La línea de código use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage; importa la clase Storage del espacio de nombres Illuminate\Support\Facades. La clase Storage proporciona una API para acceder a archivos almacenados en diferentes sistemas de almacenamiento, como el sistema de archivos local, Amazon S3, nexcloud, etc.

La línea de código $fileContents = Storage::get('nombre_del_archivo'); obtiene el contenido del archivo con el nombre nombre_del_archivo del sistema de almacenamiento predeterminado. El resultado es una cadena que contiene el contenido del archivo.

Por ejemplo, el siguiente código obtendrá el contenido del archivo public/file.txt y lo imprimirá en la consola:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$fileContents = Storage::get('public/file.txt');

echo $fileContents;
```

Comment: Está respuesta aparece como de [baja calidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/396288). Tal vez sea más adecuado escribirlo en un comentario o debas explayarte un poco más.

Comment: @Mateo es una respuesta clara, tan clara que si no la comprendes no eres un programador Jr laravel

Comment: Mí intención era informarte que alguien o el propio sistema detectó tu publicación como de baja calidad. Haz lo que creas conveniente.

Comment: @Mateo espero no me bannen por dar mas detalles de lo necesario o como de costumbre